# Dissolve Leaflet VectorGrid polygon at tile boundary by ID

Tags: leaflet, dissolve, vector-tiles

I am using Leaflet and the [Leaflet.VectorGrid](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) plugin to display vector tiles on a map. My vector tiles contain Polygons that render fine, except that they are also rendering the split at the tile boundary (see image below).

I have added the `getFeatureID` function to the creation options, so that the VectorGrid plugin knows which parts of a polygon belong together.

Is it possible to not draw the polygon boundaries at the edges of the tiles, so that it looks like one large polygon?

I did not find out how to do it (other than using a fill sytle but no outline). If it is not possible with this plugin, is there an alternative?

[image: Polygons in vector tiles split at tile boundary]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not the VectorGrid library, but the underlying data. The vector tiles are not really dissolved geometrically on the frontend. The data is clipped on the backend with a small buffer around the tile boundary, so that the clip boundary is outside the tile boundaries and is therefore not rendered. For more details, see

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/issues/120